# Take two integers a,b and print all the even numbers in between them, excluding the input integers

Tags: loops, for-loop, numbers

Take two integers a,b and print all the even numbers in between them, excluding the input integers.

Constraints:

0 <= a < b <= 100

Input:

Two integers each in a new line.

Output:

Each line in the output contains an even integer between a,b in ascending order.

Example:

Input:

3

12

Output:

4

6

8

10

I could not find it's logic.

Comment: *...I could not find its logic...* You need to more specific and clear. Clearly you understand what an even number so what **exactly** are you having a problem with?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the question that well, but here's what I got out of it:

```
for i in range(a + 1, b):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(i)
```

This loop goes through every letter between your 2 constraints (a and b), checks if its divisible by 2, and if it is (which means it's even), it prints it.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Input
A, B = map(int, input().split())

# Output integers between A and B (excluding A and B)
for i in range(A+1, B):
    print(i, end=" ")

# Output the number of integers printed
print(B - A - 1)
```